# Is it ok/necessary to unsubscribe from Events outside dispose method? Possibly wrong code design

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mvvm, blazor

I'm in a situation where I have to new up a ViewModel that has an event and based on the view chosen by the user I might need to swap back and forth between this one and other ViewModels with the same interface, every time they have to get the updated data.
These ViewModel contains a list of ViewModels that I need to display.

Is it ok to do detach and attach to the event this way outside the usual Dispose method?

```
if (_animalsListVm is not null)
{
    _animalsListVm.MyEvent -= Handle_MyEvent;
}

_animalsListVm = MakeListViewModel();
_animalsListVm.MyEvent += Handle_MyEvent;
await _animalsListVm.InitializeAsync();
```

Granted this code might be messy, I'm using Blazor and I was trying to find an alternative to have enums or booleans to show a component, so I decided to switch view based on the concrete type of the current ViewModel.

Comment: That's totally OK and quite a common thing to have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching and detaching events outside dispose methods is generally fine.

In some cases a pattern like this might be preferable:

```
public IDisposable RegisterForEvent(Action<EventArguments> eventHandler);
```

This follows the typical dispose pattern. This pattern might be preferable if you need to do some work when registering or unregistering events. You could do the same with a regular event, but I would typically not expect an event registration to do any time consuming work.

I am however not a fan of initialization methods. While they can be hard to avoid, I prefer objects that are completely constructed when the constructor returns, perhaps something like:

```
_animalsListVm?.Dispose();
_animalsListVm = await MakeListViewModel(Handle_MyEvent);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips! i will use that pattern for sure. In regard of the initialize method, I think I could put that initialization method inside the make method. I though that being a side effects would be better outside. As for avoiding it, the constructor can't use async await right? I wanted that viewmodel to get the data from the db itself. I'm not very sure which responsability goes where tbh...

Comment: @Taunterexd Yes, the constructor cannot be async. A possible workaround is to make the constructor private, and add a static `Create` method that constructs the object and does all the initialization, that at least keeps all the initialization inside the same class.